# Adding particular data to particular sheets within one document

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am a bit new at this and am having a tough time getting this to work...

I have multiple sheets, one main one (Submissions) which receives data from a form, then I have the sheets:
Level 1, Level 2, Level 3, Level 4, Level 5

When data (all text, into B:B) is received, I grade it manually with a number in C:C, still all within Submissions.

What I would like to do is sort this text data into the sheets based on the graded levels, 1 to 5, so data in B1:B1 graded level 1 in C1:C1 should go into sheet Level 1, while data in B14:B14 graded level 3 in C14:C14 should go into sheet Level 3.

I have tried my hand at `=Query` with nested `=If`, or `=If` with nested `=Query`, but I'm definitely missing something and over my head...

Code for Level 1 sheet I had which seemed to make the most sense but does not work:

```
=IF(Submissions!C:C = "1", =QUERY(Submissions!B:C,Submissions!B2:B136),)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like:

```
=query(Submissions!B:C,"select B, C where C = 1")
```

where the number would need to be changed as the formula is applied in different sheets.